# Need advice in throwing Exception in Java method

Tags: java, android, performance

I am writing a method, in this I need to check that all the parameters I am receiving are not null. If any parameter is null, I need to print that custom message in as `Exception.`

My code look like this:

```
 public void checkParam(String emp,String id,String addr)
    {
    try{ 
      if(emp == null)
       throw new Exception("Error: Missing emp");
    else if(id== null)
       throw new Exception("Error: Missing id");
    else if(addr== null)
       throw new Exception("Error: Missing addr");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
    }
//if no exception

//do some action on params
}
```

My question is:

1. The above procedure is proper way for my requirement?
2. New Exception -- does it create lots of memory, is there any other way to simply doing this?

Comment: In Java 7, look into `Objects.requireNonNull(Object)`. The exception should be unchecked and you should document it. And don't catch it in the same place you throw it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this function as follows however you need to catch the exception where you will call this  function.

```
public void checkParam(String emp,String id,String addr) throws Exception
    {

      if(emp == null){
       throw new Exception("Error: Missing emp");}
    else if(id== null){
       throw new Exception("Error: Missing id");}
    else if(addr== null){
       throw new Exception("Error: Missing addr");}

//if no exception write some more code

//do some action on params
}
```

and when you will call this function do as follows

```
try {//pass valuse
        checkParam(emp,id,addr)
    }
    catch(Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }
```

also visit

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/exceptions_throwing.shtml

http://www.akadia.com/services/java_exceptions.html

http://www.functionx.com/java/Lesson15.htm

Answer (score 0):

You are catching the exception that you created, which in this case, nothing will happen. To throw the exception out:

```
public void checkParam(String emp, String id, String addr) throws Exception {
    if(emp == null)
        throw new Exception("Error: Missing emp");
    if(id == null)
        throw new Exception("Error: Missing id");
    if(addr == null)
        throw new Exception("Error: Missing addr");
}
```

This may crash the app if you do not catch the error outside of this function.

Or, if you just wanna make sure the params are there without crashing, just return a boolean.

```
public boolean checkParam(String emp, String id, String addr) {
    return emp != null && id != null && addr != null;
}
```

Even better, if you do not need to know which variable is actually missing, just create a function which accepts different amount of params:

```
public boolean checkParam(String... param) {
    if(param != null) {
        int size = param.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if(param[i] == null)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are catching the exceptions yourself. So in case any of the parameters is null, the caller will not know of any error that has happened in your method.

You should instead throw the exception from your code in case of invalid parameter being passed

```
public void checkParam(String emp,String id,String addr) throws IllegalArgumentException{
//check for exceptions
//your code after throwing the exceptions
}
```

Also, instead of just throwing `Exception`, use specific type of exception to exactly indicate the cause of error like `IllegalArgumentException` in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
public void checkParam(String emp,String id,String addr)
    {
      if(emp == null || id == null || addr == null) {

          // the conditional operator checking has same behavior 
          // as your if - else, to find, which parameter is null
          // it report first ever parameter which is null
          throw new Exception("Error: Missing "+ emp == null ? "emp" : id == null ? 
                              "id" : add == null ? "addr" : "" );

      }
      // control will reach here if no exception occured

}
```